# Javascript dont Work in SharePoint 2016

Tags: javascript, web-part

java script dosent Works with content editor or editor script web part in Sharepoint 2016

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably "custom script" feature is enabled and preventing the script editor from executing

Comment: how can allow custom script in sharepoint 2016 ?

Comment: Below link might help: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37533.sharepoint-online-how-to-enable-custom-script.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to save after then open browser developer console and reload page.
Are there any errors in console? May be other script above has errors.

Comment: it's a simple alert script and is work very well in Sharepoint 2013

Comment: 1 warning : [Deprecation] 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead. start.js?rev=i3DGUGjKFnPXSyW39iWxzw%3D%3DTAG0:1

Comment: What browser do you use?
Is it working in IE?